# application crashes if the server is closed due to timeout. How can I catch it?

Tags: android, tomcat, connection, timeout, httpurlconnection

```
            String urlStr = "nana.com/nana/api/v1"
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
        else {

        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        } 
        rd.close();

        conn.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

This code works for me if the server is active and working, but when I shut the server down it goes into timeout and crashes 'unexpectedly'. All I want is that the application to say or display a alertdialog if the server is unreachable.
This is my logcat:

```
              09-14 11:52:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(17256):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
              09-14 11:52:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(17256):  at                                     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
              09-14 11:52:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(17256):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
              09-14 11:52:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(17256):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
              09-14 11:52:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(17256):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
              09-14 11:52:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(17256):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
              09-14 11:52:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(17256):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
              09-14 11:52:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(17256):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
              09-14 11:52:57.742: E/(179): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: Can you post logcat here?

Comment: @VishalPawale right away.

Comment: Have you given Internet permissions? And are you doing network operation on main thread?

Comment: @VishalPawale yep it's all go. They are not the problem, the problem is what I should do for the app not to crash if there is 'no' server online to connect to. How can I make the app say ("sorry the server is down")

Comment: @VishalPawale it's not the main thread either. I just want it to display an error message

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
public String getData(String url) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(SetHttpParams.setHttp(
            50000, 50000));

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            org.apache.http.HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                String res = Functions.convertStreamToString(instream);
            }
        }
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

String res is your string where the response will be stored. Call the above function in Asyntasks doinBackground() method. Put some local Boolean variables to check if exception occurred. And in onPostExecute() show dialog if exception occurred or continue with your work.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for you informative answer but I am using httpurlconnection, is there any chance that you could give one example for that?

Comment: You need to say *why* all this is an answer. You also need to justify your apparent recommendation of empty catch blocks to ignore certain exceptions.

Comment: @EJP: i have said in my answer put some boolean to check if exception occurred, so the boolean can be assigned in the exception blocks and can be checked in post execute method of AsyncTask. If there is anything wrong in my code please let me know.

Comment: In other words all that code isn't an answer at all: the only answer is in the last paragraph. So what's the code for?

Comment: @EJP: Dennis Able looks like a newbie here so just explained him with some code.